# Calculations based on a column with distinct elements

Tags: postgresql

this code works but would love to add a calculated column

```
SELECT x ,y ,column1       
FROM BASE1 as a
inner join BASE2 
ON BASE1.ID = BASE2.ID ;
```

I want to add a row or column that will contain "the results"  based on information in the column1. The column1 contains 2 distinct elements "YES" and "NO"   I would love to count each of them divided by the total of the summation of the two.

EX: lets say there are 3 YES and 5 NO
I would love to obtain a result of  3/8 = 0.375 for the YES a
nd 5/8 = 0.625 for the NO
I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT x ,
y ,
column1, 
((COUNT (*) where column1= YES ) / COUNT (*) ) AS COLUMN_YES, 
((COUNT (*) where column1= NO ) / COUNT (*) ) AS COLUMN_NO

FROM BASE1 as a
inner join BASE2 
ON BASE1.ID = BASE2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `GROUP BY` function to get the count for each pair.
I don't know what your x,y, column1 values look like, I assume the result look like this.

| x | y | column1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | YES |
| a | b | NO |
| a | b | YES |
| a | b | NO |
| a | b | NO |
| a | b | NO |
| a | b | NO |
| a | b | YES |
| c | d | YES |
| c | d | YES |
| c | d | YES |
| c | d | YES |
| c | d | NO |
| d | e | NO |

You will need to group by x, y column, and use `COUNT` with condition `CASE WHEN <condition> END` to determine we only increase the count if our condition is met, in our case, the condition is equals to `YES`, or `NO`

```
WITH sample_table(x, y, column1)
AS (
    VALUES
    ('a', 'b', 'YES'),
    ('a', 'b', 'NO'),
    ('a', 'b', 'YES'),
    ('a', 'b', 'NO'),
    ('a', 'b', 'NO'),
    ('a', 'b', 'NO'),
    ('a', 'b', 'NO'),
    ('a', 'b', 'YES'),
    ('c', 'd', 'YES'),
    ('c', 'd', 'YES'),
    ('c', 'd', 'YES'),
    ('c', 'd', 'YES'),
    ('c', 'd', 'NO'),
    ('d', 'e', 'NO')    
)
SELECT sample_table.x, sample_table.y,
-- only increase count if the answer is 'YES'
COUNT(CASE WHEN sample_table.column1 = 'YES' THEN 1 END) AS total_yes,
-- only increase count if the answer is 'NO'
COUNT(CASE WHEN sample_table.column1 = 'NO' THEN 1 END) AS total_no,
-- count all, to get total
COUNT(*) AS total_yes_no,
-- yes ratio = total_yes / total record
COUNT(CASE WHEN sample_table.column1 = 'YES' THEN 1 END)::decimal / COUNT(*) AS yes_ratio,
-- no ratio = total_no / total record
COUNT(CASE WHEN sample_table.column1 = 'NO' THEN 1 END)::decimal / COUNT(*) AS no_ratio
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY sample_table.x, sample_table.y
ORDER BY sample_table.x, sample_table.y;
```

will give

| x | y | total_yes | total_no | total_yes_no | yes_ratio | no_ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 3 | 5 | 8 | 0.37500000000000000000 | 0.62500000000000000000 |
| c | d | 4 | 1 | 5 | 0.80000000000000000000 | 0.20000000000000000000 |
| d | e | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1.00000000000000000000 |

Or instead of using `COUNT CASE WHEN`, you can use `FILTER` function for Postgres 9.4 and later

```
SELECT sample_table.x, sample_table.y,
-- only increase count if the answer is 'YES'
COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE sample_table.column1 = 'YES') AS total_yes,
-- only increase count if the answer is 'NO'
COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE sample_table.column1 = 'NO') AS total_no,
-- count all, to get total
COUNT(*) AS total_yes_no,
-- yes ratio = total_yes / total record
COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE sample_table.column1 = 'YES')::decimal / COUNT(*) AS yes_ratio,
-- no ratio = total_no / total record
COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE sample_table.column1 = 'NO')::decimal / COUNT(*) AS no_ratio
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY sample_table.x, sample_table.y
ORDER BY sample_table.x, sample_table.y;
```